# How can I echo a message with newlines so it is displayed with line breaks and is available under :messages

Tags: vimscript, neovim, error, command

Consider the following:

```
function! RunWithErrorHandling(command) abort
  let view = winsaveview()
  let errorOutputFile = tempname()

  let shellredir_save = &shellredir
  let &shellredir = '>%s 2>' . errorOutputFile
  silent execute a:command
  let &shellredir = shellredir_save

  if v:shell_error != 0
    silent undo
    echohl ErrorMsg
    for error in readfile(errorOutputFile)
        echoerr error
    endfor
    echohl None
  endif

  call delete(errorOutputFile)
  call winrestview(view)
endfunction

command! JsonToDict call RunWithErrorHandling('% ! python -c "import json; import sys; as_dict = json.load(sys.stdin); print(as_dict)"')
```

I've got multiple of these commands calling external commands (not just python) and I have wrapped them with RunWithErrorHandling (adapted from https://github.com/hashivim/vim-terraform) so that I can get an error message instead of replacing the buffer content with the error.

I've been struggling with getting an error message displayed properly because multiline messages would have `\n` replaced with `^@` instead of adding a line break when using `echoerr` and `echom`.

Using `echo` in combination with `echohl ErrorMsg` displays everything the way I want, but the message is not available using `:messages`.

I ended up with the for loop and multiple calls to `echoerr` as shown above, but it feels wrong and a multiline message is broken up into several "vim messages" so `:1messages` shows me only the last line of a multiline message instead of the whole message.

It would be nice if I could echo the message so it's displayed the same way it is now and `:1messages` shows me the whole message.

It seems like it should be possible because when I get an error running the following command:

```
command! DictToJson % python3 function_that_raises_an_exception()
```

I do get a nice stacktrace and `:1messages` shows me the whole thing.

Comment: As an aside, you may want to consider doing the cleanup (`let &shellredir = shellredir_save`, `delete(errorOutputFile)`, `winrestview(view)`) in a `finally` block so it always gets run. [Example](https://github.com/arp242/gopher.vim/blob/master/autoload/gopher/system.vim#L161-L177). Also see `:help try-finally`.

Comment: What do you think can fail? Because `silent execute a:command` never throws an exception, no matter what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to split on newlines and run `echomsg` multiple times; usually it's easiest to create a little wrapper function for this; for example:

```
fun! s:echo(msg) abort
   for line in a:msg->split('\n')
       echom line
   endfor
endfun
```

Or:

```
fun s:error(msg) abort
   echohl Error
   for line in a:msg->split('\n')
       echom line
   endfor
   echohl None
endfun
```

And then `:call s:error("asd\nzxc")` will output:

```
asd
zxc
```

I typically use `echom` for this as it doesn't include a line number like `echoerr`, which I rarely find useful, but you can use `echoerr` too if you prefer that.

---

A more expansive version of the above would be:

```
" Output an error message to the screen. The message can be either a list or a
" string; every line will be echomsg'd separately.
fun! s:error(msg, ...) abort
  call s:echo(a:msg, 'ErrorMsg', a:000)
endfun

" Output an informational message to the screen. The message can be either a
" list or a string; every line will be echomsg'd separately.
fun! s:info(msg, ...) abort
  call s:echo(a:msg, 'Debug', a:000)
endfun

" Echo a message to the screen and highlight it with the group in a:hi.
"
" The message can be a list or string; every line with be :echomsg'd separately.
fun! s:echo(msg, hi, ...) abort
  if type(a:msg) is v:t_list
    let l:msg = a:msg
  else
    let l:msg = a:msg
    if len(a:000) > 0 && len(a:000[0]) > 0
      let l:msg = call('printf', [a:msg] + a:000[0])
    endif
    let l:msg = split(l:msg, "\n")
  endif

  " Tabs display as ^I or <09>, so manually expand them.
  let l:msg = map(l:msg, { _, v -> substitute(l:v, "\t", '      ', '') })

  " Redrawing here means there will be a better chance for messages to show.
  redraw

  exe 'echohl ' . a:hi
  for l:line in l:msg
    echom 'MYPLUGINNAME: ' . l:line
  endfor
  echohl None

  " Add a delay when called from insert mode, because otherwise the user will
  " never see the message.
  " TODO: maybe there is a better way? I can't find one if there is...
  if mode() is# 'i' && a:hi is# 'ErrorMsg'
    sleep 1
  endif
endfun
```

This also handles lists (`call s:error(['line1', 'line2'])`), does `printf` formatting, and automatically prefixes lines with `MYPLUGINNAME:` , which I find nice.

Probably overkill for your case though, but I've used it in some larger plugins.

Comment: This still has the same problem of only giving the last line of the message for `:1messages` instead of the whole message?

Comment: Oh right, I missed that you already mentioned this in your question @SebastianBlask; sorry about that  I don't think there's any other way of doing this, short of joining the message by spaces. While `:{count}messages` is documented as "Show the {count} most recent messages." in reality it just means "most recent *lines*". It behaves like this for something like `throw 'err'` (which outputs two lines) as well: `:1mess` will just show the last one.